# CPU fan doesn't stay on in ubuntu 16

Tags: acer, overheating, fan

I have a acer aspire 5315, recently put ubuntu 16 on there for development. The fan comes on on start up and going through the bios but once it boots ubuntu the fan turns off, this then causes the pc to get hot and switch off.

I have installed and ran lm-sensors and the fan isn't even listed, I have also tried sensors-detect and still nothing. I then tried installing fan control and still no joy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you